# Apache Solr Boolean Search 100% Match

Tags: solr

I have 2 docs in my apache solr with following values of field

```
custom_value: haris mehmood

custom_value: hari mehmood
```

I am trying to do a boolean search and using dismax and my query is `+haris`, I do the following:

```
defType=dismax & mm=100% & ps=0 & q=+haris & wt=json
```

*P.S: I added spaces myself in query string for better understanding*

I just want 1 result in response that should be the first one i.e. `haris mehmood` and not the one with `hari mehmood`

I want to know what is it that I am doing wrong and if not, is there a way to achieve what I want.

Comment: What is the fieldType of `custom_value` ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam its `text_en`

Comment: Why don't you use `The Standard Query Parser` ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam it has the same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to handle non English text in that query/field, then use a different analysis, not doing any English language stuff.

text_en does probably some stemming and the s in 'haris' is being removed, so it matches your query.

Comment: Hmm, that might be right, because if I do `+haria` instead of `+haris` it returns no doc

Comment: That is infact the right answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are using fieldType `text_en`. It has a filter `Porter Stem Filter` which stemming your word and remove the trailing `s`.

Create a new fieldType without the `Porter Stem Filter`

```
<fieldType name="text_simple" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
        />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
    />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

And change your fieldType to `text_simple` and reload the core and reindex data